# Android - Displaying Polyline

Tags: java, android, google-maps

The concept of my application is that a a path is drawn every time a user sets two markers on a map and that path is shown in another activity. I have saved the path (waypoints) as an Array list in my FireBase database and I have also retrieved the way points in the second activity, but I am having problems displaying the poly line in the second activity. My database:

[image]

My POJO classes:

```
public static class Route {

    private ArrayList<Location> locations;

    public Route() {
    }

    @PropertyName("route")
    public ArrayList<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    @PropertyName("route")
    public void setLocations(ArrayList<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}


public static class Location {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Retrieval of waypoints:

```
 userRef.child("Route").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
            for (Location location : route.getLocations()) {
                points = new ArrayList();
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
        }
```

To add the polyline to the map I do this:

```
 PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
    lineOptions.add(position);
    lineOptions.width(12);
    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

    mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

But I get this exception :

> "NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions.add(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)' on a null object reference"

Comment: first instantiate it

Comment: ur keeping it null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about writing

```
PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
```

instead of

```
PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
```

Also you are adding a single point in the polyline. Loop through your list `points` and add all of them.

```
for (LatLng point: points){
    lineOptions.add(point);
}
mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Your another mistake:

You are recreating the ArrayList as `points = new ArrayList();` inside for loop. Use it before for loop.

```
points = new ArrayList();
for (Location location : route.getLocations()) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: I tried this. At first I am getting this exception: "NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'double com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng.b' on a null object reference" when I then close the application and start again there is no exception, but the Polyline is not displayed

Comment: Yes, I tried looping through like you but I am getting an error on the "Latlng point" as it says: incompatible types, required Object found Latlng

Comment: Use `List<LatLng> points;` while declaring it and use `points = new ArrayList<>();` when instantiating it.

Comment: Perfect, It is working now. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the help a couple days ago. I posted a new question regarding the the same project that I am working on. If you have the time you are welcome to look at the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956890/android-drawing-multiple-polylines-with-data-from-firebase